# MVVMLight + RIA + MEF

Tags: mvvm-light

Is there an example to use, MVVMlight + MEF + RIA all together, possibly even a video.

Not sure were to start with all this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code to get you started. You can generate code with the T4 templates. NOTE: It requires [T4 Toolbox](http://t4toolbox.codeplex.com/).

[Download here](http://bit.ly/auMxfx)

Comment: if you can repost a generated sample you would be my hero.

Comment: All you have to do it add code templates folder to a silverlight web service and you can generate OData service.

Answer (score 0):

This might help: [Post from Dave Davis](http://blog.davemdavis.net/2010/07/24/silverlight-child-window-with-mef-and-mvvm-light/)

Answer (score 0):

I started with this example
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/silverlight/IssueVisionForSilverlight.aspx

It could be exactly what you need...